# how to close sql resultset, statement, connection correctly

Tags: sql, sonarqube

I am wondering, why sonarQube display error msg, that resultSet and Statement are not closed. SonarQube give me the errormsgs:

```
Close this "Statement".
Close this "ResultSet".
```

My current code looks like this:

```
try{...
 } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new FatalException(ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (res != null)
                res.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e);
        }
        try {
            if (stmt != null)
                stmt.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e);
        }
        try {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e);
        }
    }
```

SonarQube doesn't complain about conn, altho it is closed on the same way like stmt and resultset. Why does sonarQube displys the above mentioned errors on stmt and res and not on conn?

Comment: Might help seeing the try-code. Hard to tell from only seeing two relevant lines of code.

Comment: What version of SonarJava are you using? Also, it might be helpful to expand your code block to show the definitions and assignments of `res` and `stmt`